# New paragraph in Swagger description when using JSON

Tags: json, swagger-2.0, github-flavored-markdown

How can I create a new paragraph when writing a description in Swagger when using JSON?

I only find examples for YAML and when I simply create a new paragraph as I would with Markdown, the validation fails and the document does not render anymore.

**What I want**

> The first paragraph describes the call.
>
> Another paragraph gives additional information about the call.

**What I tried but does not work**

```
"description": "The first paragraph describes the call.

Another paragraph gives additional information about the call.",
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON doesn't support literal multiline strings.

Replacing line breaks with `\n` should work, e.g.:

```
"description": "The first paragraph describes the call.\n\nAnother paragraph gives additional information about the call.",
```

Comment: Only tried a single `\n` which did not have any effect and gave up.

Comment: @mrplow, that would give you a line break but since the description field is formatted using GitHub Flavored Markdown paragraphs must be separated with a blank line, hence the second `\n`.